# Parity json.ipc file permissions

Tags: parity, ipc

How can I give permission for another non-priv user on the same server to get Read/Write access /home/parity/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/json.ipc and have that access available on reboot?

The .toml file does not have anything to specify the file permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the correct permissions [isn't something parity handles](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/9703), but setting permissions after the socket is created (using chmod/chown) shouldn't cause any problems.

If you want to persist the permissions over reboots, you should either run parity through a script that changes the permissions after launch, or more simply, set the permissions on the directory that the socket will exist in instead of the socket itself.

Comment: @Joshup_Mir your answer looks correct but it is not the correct way for Parity to handle this.  I added a comment to the GitHub thread you posted.